Request focus before composable appears on screen
I have a compose screen that has a variable number of buttons depending on the uiState.
When one of my button appears, I want it to have the focus right away.
I've read that the best way to request the focus on a composable was to do it on the onGloballyPositioned modifier. So I did this:
Row {
        FirstActionButton()
        if (uiState.showSecondButton) {
            SecondActionButton(modifier = Modifier
                            .focusRequester(secondButtonFocusRequester)
                            .onGloballyPositioned { secondButtonFocusRequester.requestFocus() }
            )
        }
}

The problem is, the button appears and then is focused, quite fast. So it appears with its non-focused color and changes to its focused color, which appears as a kind of glitch, latency, and is quite ugly.
How could I prevent that ? Is it possible to request the focus before the button is visible ?

Interesting. AFAIK, I don't think this is possible to do at this point of time. You can file a feature request for this.
